# Which is simpler for using kerberos, Axis2 or CXF?

Tags: authentication, cxf, apache-axis, kerberos

I am new to this field so please take it easy on me if I say something stupid
I am trying to use kerberos with web services and am not sure which is more suited
Axis2's rampart uses WSSJ 1.6.2 which supports kerberos tokens, can someone give me more information on how CXF works with kerberos? from what I found, I need to use spengo but I am lost

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kerberos support in WSS4J was developed primarily for CXF by a CXF developer.   You're likely better off with CXF.   You can check his blog on the topic:

http://coheigea.blogspot.com/2011/10/using-kerberos-with-web-services-part.html